# Check csv columns before adding to df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to import csv files to Dataframe, I use pd.read_csv.
But I have many csv files to import which have not exactly the same columns, but still a few in common.
I can not change the csv files has they come from different sources but are mixed when I get them, and with the name i can not filter them. Also, I can not import it all and then filter the DataFrame because some columns are in common.

Is ther a way to check the number of columns or if a certain column is in the csv fil before adding it to the Dataframe ?

something like:
read_csv(source) if 'XXXX' is in CSV

thank you !

Comment: Read with `nrows=1` in `read_csv` params, check the columns, read the entire file if conds met. Another solution would be to write a function that reads the first line and checks col info.

Comment: You can use `len(df.columns)` to check columns number

Comment: I guess those manipulations are easier done when the csv is already loaded. Can you not just load the csv to a different dataframe, check the data it contains and then only add the data you want (e.g. the columns which are not in common) to the bigger frame?

Comment: `pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv' , usecols = ['col1','col2'])`

Comment: RakeshV I can not use this as both type of CSV have columns in common
@SayandipDutta indeed regarding the function, but how would I call it, before the read_csv or is there a haw to apply it in the read_csv

Comment: Seems like a simple if check before calling `read_csv` would do. `for fname in dir: if check_cols(fname):read_csv(fname)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If answer is useful to anyone:
As I was using list comprehension I added the if statement:

```
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files if all(c in list(pd.read_csv(f, nrows=1))
     for c in colonnes_data) ], keys=files, axis=0)
```